# Django - Campo CharField cria campo Int no BD

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Tenho um projeto simples aqui, com duas models que contem um atributo chamado telefone em ambas.

```
class Medico (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cpf = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    especialidade = models.ForeignKey(Especialidade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Paciente (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cpf = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Fiz o makemigrations e migrate, tudo funcionou direitinho como previsto, estou utilizando o **MySQL** como BD.

Mas por algum motivo, o campo **telefone** está como int no meu BD tanto para a tabela paciente quanto para a tabela medico, veja na imagem:

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já os demais campos estão corretos, alguém saberia me dizer por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o aumento de arquivos na pasta no diretório seuapp/migrations/**pychache**, pode causar alguns conflitos na hora de fazer migrações para o banco de dados.

Neste caso, tem duas formas de resolver.

Primeira forma:

- Exclua todos os arquivos da pasta  seuapp/migrations/**pychache** (COM EXEÇÃO DO ARQUIVO **init**.py)
- Execute os comandos a seguir: `python manage.py makemigrations`  e `python manage.py migrate`.

Isso pode resolver o problema.

Já no meu caso, o buraco foi mais em baixo, tive que excluir o banco de dados inteiro, excluir os arquivos mencionados na etapa 1 e posteriormente recriar o banco.

Explicando Segunda forma: (resolveu meu problema)

- Exclua o banco de dados
- Exclua todos os arquivos da pasta  seuapp/migrations/**pychache** (COM EXEÇÃO DO ARQUIVO **init**.py)
- Crie o Banco novamente
- Execute os comandos a seguir: `python manage.py makemigrations`  e `python manage.py migrate`.